# What does the "fh" suffix mean on a number like "38fh" in Intel assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, masm, radix

I've searched all over the web, but I couldn't find what the "fh" means in the following instruction `and eax, 38fh`. I know that "h" stands for hexadecimal and "d" for decimal, but I've never seen fh before.

Comment: It's the number *3f8* in hexadecimal. Literal ending in *h* specify number in hexadecimal. *3f8h* is *1016* in decimal.

Comment: Of course! That was very stupid of me... Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. You are not alone in such mistakes, for example I mistyped the number, it's actually 38f not 3f8 :)

Comment: Voting to close as typo.  And retitling to `38fh`, because `fh` is a symbol name, not a numeric constant.  (write `0fh`, or `0xf` in flavours of asm that allow C-style hex constants.)

Comment: @MargaretBloom , make a answer instead of a comment ;-)

Comment: One trick would be to use a different capitalization to make the suffix stand out: __38Fh__.

Comment: @Fifoernik That's indeed a nice trick to make this more clear! Thanks :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom : Easy mistake to make since 3f8h actually has meaning  if you are dealing with a port number ;-). I saw it as 3f8h at first too and assumed he was doing some serial port development.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Although the original title only mentioned `fh`, the body of the question itself isn't a typographical error. `and eax, 38fh` is perfectly valid in Intel assemblers like MASM etc (ones that take the `h` suffix). I don't see how you can vote to close for a **typo**. In this case asking what `fh` means in the context of `38fh` in my opinion doesn't constitute a typo. If the instruction (with the immediate) was invalid sure, but it isn't.

Comment: And I think it is a fair question as I know others have had issues with understanding values with an `h` suffix. So it could very well be something someone else would be interested in. It is probably a duplicate (or close to one) of another question but I didn't find one.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I'm including "brain fart" / "misreading" in the general category of "typo".  Retitling to save people the trouble of looking at the question at all is a separate thing.  However, maybe you're right that other people will have the same brain fart and manage to find this question.  `fh` is probably more common than `ah` or `ch`  (in hex constants, not register names).  I was mostly thinking it should be closed based on the unlikeliness of someone else having the same confusion and searching the same way, but I'll retract my close vote since you make a good argument.

Comment: @PeterCordes : No problem. Since my answer was the input of a number of commenters to at least give this question a solution I marked it at the time of creation as Community Wiki since I wasn't looking to establish an answer for reputation. How you word questions like this for better searching is tougher. But in my searches (including another answer I gave last year) I could only find things that are related. If someone can think of a better title for the question I'd say have at it. If there is a duplicate out there that is close, marking this as duplicate is a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an Intel assembler (ie. *MASM*) token starts with a number (0 to 9) then it is assumed to be that the entire token is a value. If the value ends with an `h` the assembler assumes it is *H*exadecimal.

In your case `38fh` starts with a number so it is assumed to be a value. The end of the token in your case is `h`(or `H`) so it is treated as hexadecimal number. So `38f` is treated as a hexadecimal value. The `f` just happens to be a valid hexadecimal digit. `38f` is 911 in decimal and 1110001111 in binary.

A problem does arise if you have a token like `f8h`. Because it starts with a letter (not a digit 0 to 9) it will be treated as an identifier or symbol. This will likely lead to some form of syntax error if it appeared as `and eax, f8h` . The question one may have - if a hexadecimal value starts with a letter *A* to *F* how can I represent it using an `h` suffix? Simple, just place a 0 on the front. This would work `and eax, 0f8h` .

As Fifoernik pointed out *One trick would be to use a different capitalization to make the suffix stand out: **38Fh*** . It might have been easier for a human new to assembler to see that `f` was a hexadecimal digit had it been made upper case `F` while leaving the suffix character 'h' lower case.